# jQuery Simulatenous animation

Tags: jquery

After loads of googling and still not being able to solve the problem, i have to trouble you guys again.
http://goo.gl/Ibcdp
If you look on the top right side, you will notice a search box. It has a nice little animation effect that runs on focus. The full script is here:
http://goo.gl/VFBuk

Now I want the 2 animation events(shrinking the other menu items(i am using two classes, a normal one, and an item_selected class rendered server side) and enlarging the width of the search container div(#the_search_field) to run perfectly simultaneous. If you look close, you will notice how there is a tiny gap created for a few seconds in between the last two items.

This is because there is a delay between animations..also, in firefox this brakes down even further and because of that delay, the sum of widths of menu items exceeds the total width of the container and overflows it, which causes everything to break for a split second.
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Something is wrong, check in Firefox. It gets all messed up.

Comment: use css animations and transitions!

Comment: You have 89 Errors, 8 warnings in that page. I'm sure some of them can be ignored but it'll put you in the right path http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.instantrepair.co.uk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: If I could make a suggestion, it would be to remove the CSS width values on the first menu item - the home button, and remove the differenece in width *only* from the home button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this demo page:

http://ejohn.org/files/sync

view the page source to see how it's done with the 'step' function.

Comment: thanks I will use the idea and edit it to suit my own needs. Cheers for that, hopefully it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to fix the completely broken firefox issue, make `#main_menu` `overflow: hidden`.  This will prevent the flow from breaking when the items are a bit too long.

As for the gap, this is a result of the fact that computation takes real time.  The animations will *always* lead or lag each other by a bit, simply because the animation function call gets called later.  You could reduce how noticeable this is by animating them together, but you would have to write a custom timeout/step function to do this.  Using 2 different jQuery calls means that you have the overhead of jQuery switching between each animation queue and updating the DOM elements.  This takes time.

Comment: Hey...good post. I just wanted to elaborate further. the 'side-effect' that he's talking about isn't a side effect, it's the exact time it takes to calculate the algorithim in place to determine the distance between the start and the finish, and the amount the offset.top and offset.left have to change, and how many times they must change. The exact time this takes varies from 2ms to 22ms to calculate this function depending on the processing power of the server. When we want to makeup for this, we use 17ms as the timeout to compensate (should really never do that, though)

Comment: I guess "a result of" would have been better wording than "a side-effect of".  But yes, computation takes time... people tend to forget that.

Comment: I meant to include the function name so people could look and test for themselves! I can be an idiot. This breaks it down really well -> http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/03/01/the-jquery-animate-step-callback-function/

Comment: hello captain obvious times 2:)